# Shell exec works wrong while exec during webhook

Tags: php, shell, webhooks, shell-exec

I have shell script to deploy project from dev.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "****** Getting latest pull ******"
cd "../../"
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/docs_autopull_build
git rebase --abort
git pull  origin dev
echo "****** Building project ******"
gulp css
gulp scripts
cd "public_html/docs/"
echo "****** Building docs ******"
npm run styleguide:build
echo "******************************************"
```

I test it via php file

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
shell_exec('sh pull_and_build.sh');
```

To test i used console php test.php exec.

But when **shell_exec('sh pull_and_build.sh');** runs via webhook its seems like wrongs inccorect.

When i am again running **php test.php** after webhook i got the result ,that should be yet via webhook.

Seems like there is difference between exec shell via php file running command line and when   shell execs by webhook.php.

webhook.php and test php exist in the same directory.

UPD:: I change the path to absolute - that doesnot helps.

On screenshots the results of git status after running test.php and after running webhook.

Seems like webhook invoke git commands and cant invoke gulp and npm.

[image: First - via test.php , second via webhook.php]

UPD2:: The  shell_exec('sudo -S sh pull_and_build.sh'); doesnot hepls

Comment: The current directory is probably not the same in the webserver, so `cd ../..` goes to a different directory. Use an absolute pathname or pass the directory as a parameter.

Comment: "seems like wrong" is not really a fixable error or problem statement. You might want to try being a bit more specific. See also [ask]